How to convert this simple CLI program to run on browser?
I've created some simple programs using Python that basically asks users questions for introspection. It asks one question at a time based on previous answer. I'd like for users to be able to login and store their answers in a database. Any suggestions on which route to take with this? What languages and/or frameworks would you recommend to run on the web for others to use? Or are there any pre-existing online site-builders websites that would allow this functionality?
Example questions:
1. What is your goal? (user input)
2. Why do you want [response to question 1]? (user input)
3. Why do you want [response to question 2]? (user input)
4....


you need to use JSON format and javascript  for codding this.

Take a look at Django and Flask for examples of Python web frameworks.

web pages work in different way than programs in console or in GUI - and it may need many changes. Sometimes it may need to write code in JavaScript

if you want to run in browser then better first learn HTML, CSS and JavaScript

if you do it as a hobby then you can run it on replit.

I made a very simple program with flask to give you some ideas
(Make sure you run pip install flask)
Create a file named app.py:
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

# In-memory database (for simplicity)
questions = {
    1: "What is your goal?",
    2: "Why do you want [answer to question 1]?",
}
answers = {}  # Stores user answers

app = Flask(__name__)  # No need to specify template folder

max_question = max(questions.keys())

@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def index():
    if request.method == "POST":
        answer = request.form.get("answer")
        current_question = int(request.form.get("current_question"))
        answers[current_question] = answer
        next_question = current_question + 1
        if next_question > max_question:
            # Save answers to a text file
            save_answers()
            return "Thank you for your answers!"
        return render_template("questions.html", question=questions[next_question], current_question=next_question, max_question=max_question)
    return render_template("questions.html", question=questions[1], current_question=1, max_question=max_question)

def save_answers():
    with open("user_answers.txt", "w") as file:
        for question_id, answer in answers.items():
            file.write(f"Question {question_id}: {questions[question_id]}\n")
            file.write(f"Answer: {answer}\n")
            file.write("\n")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)

Now, create a folder named "templates".
Inside the folder, create a file "questions.html"
and put this in the file
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Introspective Q&A</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Introspection</h1>
    <form method="post">
        <p>{{ question }}</p>
        <label for="answer">Your answer:</label>
        <input type="text" name="answer" id="answer" required>
        <input type="hidden" name="current_question" value="{{ current_question }}">
        <br>
        <button type="submit">Next Question</button>
    </form>
    <br>
    {% if current_question == max_question %}
        <p>Thank you for your answers!</p>
    {% endif %}
</body>
</html>

Should look like this
├── app.py
├── user_answers.txt
└── templates
    ├── login.html
    └── questions.html

Now, run in cmd "python app.py". This will create a local webserver for you. copy the address from the cmd and enter it on a web browser.
The answers of the user will be saved to user_answers.txt.
This is just an example of course, you can use this as a base for more complex programs.
